# DNN plugin in some cases gets a string from the LocalResources file in some cases does not get

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm making custom plugin for DNN site and hitting in the wall with this.
I'm trying to get strings from the resource file but it only works from ResourceKey="".
If I put

```
ToolTip='<%$Resources:btnDelete %>'
```

I get error "The resource object with key 'btnDelete' was not found"

If I try from code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

rqValName.ErrorMessage = Localization.GetString("rqValNameResource1.ErrorMessage", LocalResourceFile); 

}
```

from debugger I can see the string but does not show it on the site.

This is the code that does not work too :

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqValName" CssClass="dnnFormMessage dnnFormError" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage='<%$Resources:rqValNameResource1 %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

If I put ResourceKey="rqValNameResource1" it all good, but I can't do that here

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="700px" DataField="sShortDescription" HeaderText='<%$Resources:HeaderShortDescription %>' />
```

DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The resource object with key 'HeaderShortDescription' was not found.

And if I put ResourceKey="HeaderShortDescription" it say "Attribute ResourceKey is not a valid attribute of element BoundField".

I don't want to hardcode this because later I need to translate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
ToolTip='<%$Resources:btnDelete %>'
```

is not DNN style. ResourceKey is the correct syntax.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   rqValName.ErrorMessage = Localization.GetString("rqValNameResource1.ErrorMessage", LocalResourceFile); 

}
```

The easy way would be to add the attribute

```
ResourceKey="rqValNameResource1.ErrorMessage"
```

to the ASP.Net Validator control.

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="700px" DataField="sShortDescription" HeaderText='<%$Resources:HeaderShortDescription %>' />
```

Are you using a DataGrid control? If yes you can use the LocalizeDataGrid() method in the Grid_Init event. Example:

```
   <asp:DataGrid ID="myGrid" runat="server"...
   ...
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ShortDescription" />
```

RESX file:

Key: ShortDescription.Header
Value: Short description

Code behind:

```
protected void myGrid_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Localization.LocalizeDataGrid(ref myGrid, LocalResourceFile);
}
```

In other cases you might use this code behind in the (Control)_ItemDataBound event:

```
protected void myControl_ItemDataBound(object sender, ControlItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ListItemType == ListItemType.Header)
   {
      foreach (TableCell tc in e.Item.Cells)
      {
         tc.Text = Localization.GetString(string.Format("{0}.Header", tc.Text), LocalResourceFile);
      }
   }
}
```

(or something alike, I don't have a working example at the moment).

Happy DNNing!
Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael. This was very helpful

Comment: Can you help me out with one more problem @Michael Tobisch? I have a button that need to have onClientClick confirmation: OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')". But I can't figure it out how to get string from Resource file. I don't want this to be hard coded. Thanks

Comment: Vladimir, a bit of research could bring you forward quicker than waiting for answers, as there are a lot of examples. Have a look at the [dnnConfirm plugin](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/dnnconfirm-jquery-plugin).